# Problems with binding in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular-JS with .net web api.
the program will display list of "Profiles", and when a user click on any it will navigate to the details.

The list part works fine, but the details doesn't display any data
the code is as follows:

```
var profileModule = angular.module('profileModule', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

profileModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/profile', {
                controller: 'profileController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/profileList.html'
        })
        .when('/profile/:profileId', {
            templateUrl: 'Partials/profileDetail.html',
            controller: 'profileDetailController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/profile' });


}]);

profileModule.controller('profileController', function($scope, profileFactory) {
    $scope.profiles = [];

    function init() {
        $scope.profiles = profileFactory.query();
    }

    init();
});

profileModule.controller('profileDetailController', function ($scope, $routeParams, profileFactory) {
    $scope.profile = {};

    function init() {
        $scope.profile = profileFactory.get({ Id: $routeParams.profileId });

        }

    init();
});


profileModule.service('profileFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("api/profiles/:Id");
});
```

and the detailed page profileDetail.html looks like this

```
<div>
    <h2>profile Details</h2>
    <p>
        Name: <br/>
        {{profile.Name}}
    </p>
    {{doit}}
</div>
```

the list page profileList.html looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Profiles by sort order</h1>
    <span data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles | orderBy: 'Sequence'">
        <a data-ng-href="#/profile/{{profile.Id}}">
            {{profile.Name}}
        </a><br/>
    </span>
</div>
```

The list part works fine, and when I click on the link, I can see the rest call to the web api as follows

/profiles/4

and I can see the JSON that is returning back

but no binding at all is happening on the detail page

Comment: Are you sure the bindings are good in the detail page? Shouldn't it be profile.Name not cprofile.Name

Comment: Yes, and sorry for this.
I was playing around to see why the binding not happening, and I added c, and forgot to take it off when I wrote this question. But actually the name was correct, and still I cannot get the binding work.
Thanks , I will fix it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

get() function of $resource service can be used when your GET request to the resource returns just one object. Check your browser's developer tools, you might see an error in the console saying: "Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array".

To make your code work, modify your init() function to use query instead of get:

```
function init() {
  $scope.profile = profileFactory.query({ Id: $routeParams.profileId });
}
```

As far as I know, this should resolve your issue. If it doesn't, put a comment here.

Comment: I was busy a bit.
I just tested it, and it didn't work.
Actually when I use get method, I can see the url is being called properly with this url http://localhost/myapp/api/profiles/4, where 4 is he ID I selected.
Where when I put query it give me the error you mentioned which is "Expected response to contain an object but got an array"

Comment: Try setting the option {'get': isArray: true } to the resource configuration. I am a bit busy now, will try it and update the answer later.